# Handling Screens of Libgdx App on Android

Tags: libgdx, screen

This my way to deal with screens

I have `class GameMain extends Game` I created instance of it in each screen so I can use something like this `gameMain.setScreen()`

My question is How to move properly from one screen to another ?

I have the following :

In GameMain I `setScreen(new SplashScreen(this))`

In splash screen I `setScreen(new MenuScreen(this))` in `hide()` of splash I call its `dispose()` and so on as when player click play button in menu screen I `setScreen()` to new playScreen I also call `dispose()` in `hide()` and when he returns to Menu I `setScreen(new Menu)`

Is what I am doing wrong ?

Comment: It doesn't make sense to have more than once instance of your Game.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I normally do is I have in my main Game class a function for example called setPlayScreen(), and in that method I do something like:

```
public void setPlayScreen(params){
    //Do something with params
    setScreen(new PlayScreen())
}
```

If you have your dispose() inside your screens hide() method you shouldn't have any problems.